# brushes restore from photoshop cc

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cc-2017

How do I restore the default  brushes  that came with my photoshop cc without deleleting my special brushes i have down loaded.I lost the ones that came with photoshop.

Answer (score 2):

Restoring your default brushes will not remove brushes you have downloaded.

Open the brushes panel, click the small menu icon at the top right , and click Restore Default Brushes.

[image]